# Linker error when building Google Test project in Visual Studio 2019 with v140 build tools

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest

In Visual Studio, I would like to build a solution that includes a Google Test project with C++ unit tests of the static library produced by another project in the solution, and I want to do that with the Visual Studio 2015 (v140) build tools.

(Background: I'm working on a project requiring a library provided by a third-party vendor, and the vendor claims compatibility only up to the Visual Studio 2015 toolset. I am observing unexpected behavior out of this library, and I am trying to reproduce this issue in unit test with a configuration that is 100% compliant with what they claim is supported so that I can report it effectively.)

When I try this, I can build the project fine if I leave the platform toolset as the default (v142). But if I set the platform toolset to Visual Studio 2015 (v140), then building the project fails with this error:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol ___std_reverse_trivially_swappable_4 referenced in function "void __cdecl std::_Reverse_unchecked1<enum testing::internal::edit_distance::EditType *>(enum testing::internal::edit_distance::EditType * const,enum testing::internal::edit_distance::EditType * const,struct std::integral_constant<unsigned int,4>)" (??$_Reverse_unchecked1@PAW4EditType@edit_distance@internal@testing@@@std@@YAXQAW4EditType@edit_distance@internal@testing@@0U?$integral_constant@I$03@0@@Z)
```

The file it points to is `gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj)`. My NuGet `packages.config` file contains only this:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn" version="1.8.1.2" targetFramework="native" />
</packages>
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Launch Visual Studio 2019 and Create new project
2. Choose *Google Test* as project type
3. In the *Test Project Configuration* dialog, leave the defaults (Consume Google Test as static library and C++ runtime libraries: Link dynamically)
4. Open project properties dialog, and for all configurations and all platforms, set Platform Toolset to Visual Studio 2015 (v140)
5. Build project

I think the possibilities are

- I'm just missing a setting somewhere,
- Googletest 1.8.1 is known to be incompatible with the v140 build tools, or
- this is a bug.

If it is a bug, I'm not sure whether to report it to [Google Test Adapter](https://github.com/csoltenborn/GoogleTestAdapter) or to [Googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest).

**Update**

After searching for issues relating more generally to unresolved symbols in the standard library, I suspect that my issue is a variant of the problem described here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/205947/binary-compatibility-possibly-broken-using-stdreve.html

The solution offered is:

> Thanks for reporting this issue. I'm resolving it as By Design because binary compatibility hasn't been broken here - instead, there's a rule that you need to follow.
>
> You can mix code compiled with 2015 and 2017 Updates, but the toolset that performs the final link (against the C++ Standard Library) can't be older than any of the toolsets that were used to compile the inputs. Here, you're building a static library with the 19.12 toolset, but performing the final link with the 19.11 toolset, which is too old. It's fine to mix 19.11 and 19.12 code, but the linker needs to be 19.12 or newer.

So, I imagine that the Googletest binaries provided by the NuGet package are compiled with a compiler later than 2015, and therefore the linker must match that later version.

Comment: Any idea how to tell which version was used to compile the NuGet package?